# Plotting data bases on count and categories in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data in a dataframe:

```
 Customer_ID| Customer_status| store_ID| date_of_transaction

  12352423| active | 65|2018/10/1
  12352425| inactive | 70|2018/10/1
  12352425| inactive | 65|2018/10/1
  12352426| active | 75|2018/10/1
```

The goal: to see the distribution (or avg) of inactive vs active customers per each store. This is to determine if there are some stores that have more inactive customers.

I made an extra column that has the counts for each store by using this code:

```
df_new['Counts'] =df_customer.store_id.groupby(df_customer.store_id).transform('count')
```

So now i have an extra column that has the counts for every unique store id. EX:) every entry with store id = 65 the counts column will show 32 because the store id 65 comes up 32 times in the entire data set.

I am confused on how i would graph this so I could visualize the inactivity per unique store and customer status.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the inactive average per store_id, you can use:

```
(df['Customer_status'] == 'inactive').groupby(df['store_ID']).mean()
```

Output:

```
store_ID
65    0.5
70    1.0
75    0.0
Name: Customer_status, dtype: float64
```

First create a boolean series where customer_status equals 'inactive', then group that series by store_ID, take the mean to get an average.

Plotting:

```
(df['Customer_status'] == 'inactive').groupby(df['store_ID']).mean().plot.bar(title='Average Inactive Customers Status by Store ID')
```

Output:

[image]

Update for comment, yes, reshape your dataframe a bit and plot:

```
df_out = df.groupby(['store_ID','Customer_status'])['Customer_ID'].count().unstack() 
df_out.div(df_out.sum(1), axis=0).plot.bar(title='Average Custome Status by Store ID')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks! Is there a way i could look at both inactive and active in the same plot?

Answer (score 0):

Why not :

`df.groupby(df['store_ID','Customer_status']).mean()`

Then repeat it for any other stats you want and merge dataframes.